# How to automate remote install/edit with ssh on several machines

Tags: debian, ssh

I'm trying to setup a programming environment to 14 students using Virtualbox. I have created all the individual machines but now I need to perform remote installs on every machine and I am trying to do it with a ssh script but I'm running in to several problems but my main one is that I can't login as root so I have to use a normal user and perform sudo. Every machine has the user for the student and a super user common to all.

So what I would like is to automate something like this but getting the server list from a file

```
ssh master@10.1.2.3 "echo 'password' | sudo -S ls /home/; sudo apt-get -y install vim;"
```

A better example is I need to push an updated hosts config to all the student machines

PS: I know I could have installed the software before I created the machine but the purpose of this exercise is to allow every student to do a full install from a basic debian installation

Comment: Please add technical details into exactly what you are doing and the errors you have

Comment: this might be better done with something like Ansible

Comment: +1 for Ansible, really designed for this.

Comment: Ansible is not an option. I must be able to do this with ssh and scripts

Comment: Telling students to type the `sudo` password in plain text on the command line is a Bad Idea™. Why do you feel it is necessary to use plain shell scripts for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try the *clusterssh* package, it provides you with parallel interactive SSH sessions to several hosts.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Ferenc's answer, but another option may be to use [GNU parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/).

However:

1. You definitely want Ansible for this
2. You definitely want to manage the ssh keys and not send passwords over plain text